# PHP script is not executing my statement

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to post my form with PHP. But by some reason my PHP script is not posting. When I turn error reporting on I get the following errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: date2
Notice: Undefined variable: newSingle_cal6
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent
```

I think none of these `errors` are causing the problem. The scripts sends me to `header('Location: ../error.php');` which means the script is not executed. Also when I look in phpmyadmin, I see that the database is not updated.

I have tried to execute the SQL statement in mysql and the sql statement is working.

Does someone know what is wrong in my script and how I can fix the problem?

Here is my full script:

```
<?php
    include_once('../../../../includes/db_connect.php');
    include_once('../../../../includes/functions.php');
    sec_session_start();

$correct = true;

$_SESSION['user_id'];
$pers_id = $_POST['pers_id'] ;
$name = $_POST['name'] ;
$single_cal4 = $_POST['date1'] ;
$single_cal6 = $_POST['date2'] ;

try {
    $myDateTime1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $single_cal4);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
$newSingle_cal4 = $myDateTime1->format('Y-m-d');
if(!empty($_POST['date2'])){
    try {
        $myDateTime3 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $single_cal6);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    $newSingle_cal6 = $myDateTime3->format('Y-m-d');
}

if($correct){
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'root', '');

$query = "INSERT INTO cus(user_id, pers_id, name, date1, date2) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['user_id'], $pers_id, $name, $newSingle_cal4, $newSingle_cal6));

            header('Location: ../success.php');
}else{
            header('Location: ../error.php');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few issues here:

### Notice: Undefined index: date2

This is because the index `date2` does not exist in your post (`$_POST['date2']`)

### Notice: Undefined variable: newSingle_cal6

Because `date2` does not exist in your post the variable `newSingle_cal6` is never set.

### Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

This is because the headers on your page have already been sent before you call `header('Location: ../success.php');`. This will happen if you call `header` or `echo` before that. The headers will also send if you have any raw non-php text in your file before. Make sure there is no space or anything before your opening php tag (`<?php`).

Find more information on this error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php).

Comment: But is it possible that these issues causing the problem?

Comment: @John They will definitely be causing problems. Your redirect (`header('Location: ../success.php')`) will never work, and your date object will never be set.

Comment: And how can I solve it? I know that the post for `date2` is empty. Because it is empty I am not changing the format to `('Y-m-d');`. I checked also my <?php tags. I have no spaces before or after the tags `<?php` and `?>`

Comment: @John if you are not worried about `date2` being empty ignore those warnings. As for the header issue make sure that you are not sending any headers in those `include_once`.

Comment: @John maybe try calling `sec_session_start();` at the end of your script. I think that might send headers too.

Comment: You mean here? `} sec_session_start(); ?>`

Comment: I am sending headers in `includes/functions.php`; but the headers are only for errors

Comment: I also tried to replace `$stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['user_id']` with `$stmt->execute(array('1'`but this didnt change anything

Comment: Use `if(isset($_POST['name1']))` to test if the variable is set before trying to use it.

Comment: The warning messages about the undefined variables are causing the "Headers already sent", because they're printing output before you call `header()`.